# removed from roll as administrator

Tags: facebook

im working on my app for mobile for a year and i saw that me and my colleague removed from administrator roll. we can't send FB messege about the review for the app because we are dont the administrators, so i cant contact with them about it.

i tried to remove myself as developer and readd as administrator with no success. also i sent messege in the help center of facebook with no answer for many days.

any idea how can i change it ? or who i need to talk with ?

thanks !

Comment: Ask another admin of the app to add you back if you know who the other admins are.

Comment: we both removed from the administration... so there is no administrator